# image of a two variable function in Matlab

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

Could anyone tell me how to plot the image of the following function in a two-dimensional plane in Matlab (R2018b) by possibly a Matlab code or command? I mean I want to see a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ for say, $x\in [-10,10],y\in[-10,10]$. I also don't know how to write such a function in Matlab too.

$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}5&-0.5\\3&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}8\\34\end{bmatrix}$$

Will it be something like this?

```
x=-10:10; 
y=-10:10;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=something
pcolor(X,Y,Z);
shading interp
axis('equal','square','off')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP didn't ask for "vector fields" but that is precisely what the output is:  a vector field.

The discussion of "compact set" is entirely irrelevant.

The input is a vector (position) and the output is a vector:

$$f(x,y) = (5 x - y/2 + 8, 3 x + 5 y + 34)$$

[image]

In *Mathematica*:

```
f[x_, y_] := {5 x - y/2 + 8, 3 x + 5 y + 34};
VectorPlot[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: I don't think I asked for vector fields? I guess the image will be a compact subset?How to get the plot? Thanks for ur help

Comment: @Marso I believe the below code will provide you with the picture modulo some formatting options David may have used.

`x=linspace(-10,10,20);`

`y=linspace(-10,10,20);`

`[xg,yg]=meshgrid(x,y);`

`quiver(xg,yg,5*xg+0.5*yg+8,3*xg+5*yg+34)`

.. If I may ask.. what is the picture you are expecting?

Comment: I am expecting a continuous curve as a  picture(image of the map $f$ I mean) in two dimensions co-ordinate system which is $\mathbb R^2$.  i.e providing uncountably many $(x,y)\in [-10,10]\times [-10,10]$, what will be their images under the function $f$.

Comment: @Marso:  Create an absolutely simplest example and its solution in order to convey what you're seeking (a circle, perhaps?).  Frankly, what you've written makes no sense.